# cannot show the android search dialog

Tags: android, search, dialog

I am a newbie in android, I am creating a test program to test the `search dialog` of android. 
this is **searchable.xml** config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:label="Search"
   android:hint="Type text to search">
</searchable>
```

this is **manifest** file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="luan.com.bk"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name=".SearchActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

this is the **searchActivity.java** to request search

```
    package luan.com.bk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

this is the **testActivity.java** init the search dialog

```
    package luan.com.bk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

But when I press the search key button on android simulator, the search bar not display, what is I wrong? please help. sorry because my english is not good.

Comment: Can you please provide your implementation of search button and search widget or search dialog, whatever you chose. If you don't know what I am talking about, then please have a look at this [reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

Comment: i had show all of my code, i don't know your answer more? please help

Comment: Alright, so the problem is you do not implement search widget or search dialog. Both options are described in the link that I posted earlier. Without that you won't see anything, because Search is just another view you have to display, Android won't make one for you.

Comment: i am stupid, i had sovle the problem, it is change the  android:label="Search"
   android:hint="Type text to search" to  android:label="@string/xyz"
   android:hint="@string/xyz">.Thank you for your help ^^

Comment: @VôDanh Please add that as an answer and then mark it correct. Thanks! :)

Comment: You can do it easily. see the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/44131089/3649347